# PHP/mysql search function: "error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL search embedded into a PHP code as follow:

```
<?php
include("productconfig.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM weeklytbakl") or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_POST['search'])) 
{
    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['searchbox']);

    $sql .= "WHERE description = '{$search_term}'";
}

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
?>

<form name="search_form" method="POST" action="displaydata.php">
Search: <input type="text" name="searchbox" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="search">
</form>
<table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">

<tr>
    <td><strong>ID</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Code</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Image Link</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Description</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Instock</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Week 1</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Week 2</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Week 3</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Week 4</strong></td>
    </tr>

    <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
    { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['code']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['image']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['instock']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['week1']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['week2']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['week3']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['']; ?></td>
        </tr>



        <?php }?>
        </table>
```

But the code gives me the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE description = ''' at line 1

Can you please help me identify why it's not functioning properly?

Comment: Add a space - `$sql .= " WHERE`

Comment: Be aware that the old mysql_* extension which you're using is deprecated in version 5.5 of PHP (the current version) and is being removed from version 7 (the next version). You need migrate over to using either the mysqli_* extension or PDO

Comment: you have to use like operator to get the data. if you use where, it ll look for exact keyword.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Thank you Niranjan. I'll keep that in mind. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
include("productconfig.php");
$sql = "";
$sql .= "SELECT * FROM weeklytbakl";

if (isset($_POST['search'])) 
{
    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['searchbox']);

    $sql .= " WHERE description = '{$search_term}'";
}

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! The error seems to have disappeared but when i enter something in the search box and submit. Nothing is being displayed

Comment: try changing `description = '{$search_term}'` to `description LIKE '%$search_term%'`

Comment: You're the man! Thanks a lot! Everything worked!

Answer (score 1):

Where is `$sql` declared?? Please go through syntax properly.

```
$sql .= " WHERE description = '{$search_term}'";
```

This should be

```
$sql .= "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE description = '{$search_term}'";
```

Also when you are searching, use `LIKE`

```
$sql .= "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE description LIKE '%{$search_term}%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare $sql variable first and Add space before where keyword in your query statement like below.

```
$sql .= " WHERE description = '{$search_term}'";
```